# Google Incoming Links only display for my localhost?

Tags: google-search-console, backlinks

I recently noticed that if I search google for:

```
link:mysite.com
```

There are zero results. This is false, because in Google Webmaster Tools, I have plenty of incoming links.

If I change the query to:

```
link:mysite.dev (my alias set up in /etc/hosts for local development)
```

I get results for incoming links to mysite.com! How can this be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `link:` search in Google is only intended to return a very small subset of backlinks. Google Webmaster Tools is the place to find them all. This does avoid your competitor from seeing your backlinks. [According to Matt Cutts](http://youtu.be/bF435s4xRU4) this is by design.

I think that when you search for `link:mysite.dev` it does not recognise the domain (.dev is not [a valid TLD](http://www.icann.org/en/resources/registries/tlds) so it can't possibly be a 'real' domain anyway) and it is doing a literal search. Try removing the `:` (colon)... do you get similar results?

Comment: Thank you, this was definitely the case. If i take off the TLD, it shows the expected results. Webmaster tools worked correctly, and now I understand why. Now I can just delete the incoming links widget on my WordPress dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

You need to search for `site:yourdomain.com` ([see example](http://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1SKPM_enGB448GB448&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=site%3amakejusticework.org.uk#hl=en&rlz=1C1SKPM_enGB448GB448&sclient=psy-ab&q=site%3awebmasters.stackexchange.com&oq=site%3awebmasters.stackexchange.com&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=serp.12...15168l19106l0l20529l2l2l0l0l0l0l43l82l2l2l0.frgbld.&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=fd7e4430dd3fda1a&biw=1920&bih=955)) this should return most if not all of the pages google has in it's index for your site.

You may be better of using a site like [backlinkwatch.com](http://backlinkwatch.com/) or doing both and comparing the results.